# Cross-Browsers css

Tags: asp.net, css, browser, cross-browser

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Bt_1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="clr_bt" />
.clr_bt
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Can some one please help me fix it for Opera, IE, Mozilla.

For a moment working only for Chrome.

Comment: The `-webkit` prefix will only apply styles to Chrome and Safari. This link might help: http://prefixmycss.com/

Comment: Here's a good resource on issues like this: http://caniuse.com/

Comment: IE transforms are different, and will probably require more than just a different prefix.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the vendor prefixes for the browsers to your css like this:

```
.clr_bt {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    transform: rotate(-50deg);

    -webkit-transition: 0 .5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: 0 .5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: 0 .5s ease-in;
    transition: transform .5s ease-in;
}
```

1. webkit prefix is added for `Chrome` and `Safari`
2. moz prefix is added for `Firefox`
3. ms prefix is added for `IE`
4. o prefix is added for `Opera`